# Add an empty row at the last in the DatagridView in Winform

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have one repository which contains a method which fetches the whole list from the database and the form load method as below. I have to add one empty row under the last row on a button click, so that I can edit the cells and save into database (I have another method for that).

Repository:

```
//display_tbl is storedproc
public List<ABC> FetchActiveABC() //Method for fetching the whole list into datagridview
{
    var listABC = new List<ABC>();
    try
    {
        using (var cmd = _db.GetStoredProcCommand("display_tbl"))
        {
            using (var a = new SafeDataReader(_db.ExecuteReader(cmd)))
            {
                while (a.Read())
                {
                    listABC.Add(Loadabc(a));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { /* ... */}

    return listABC;
}
```

Form:

```
private List<ABC> lstABC = null;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstABC = new ABCRepository().FetchActiveABC();
    DataGridView.DataSource = lstABC;
}
```

This displays the whole list into `datagridview`.

Comment: what did you already try?

Comment: Use a `BindingSource` or a `BindingList<ABC>` as data source of your `DataGridView`. Then easily call `AddNew` method of binding source or binding list. Just make sure `ABC` has parameterless constructor.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks, yes that worked for adding an empty row, but what if we want to add a row with some values? If we want to give some parameters?

Comment: There is also an `Add` method which accepts an instance of the object.

Comment: Yes, Using that, that doesn't add any new row, it replaces the current one. I need a new one below any row which is present in dgv.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Sarthak in stackoverflow.

As per you, you want to add one row at the last after the ABCRepository data loads.
So friend you can try this,

```
 dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
```

This code will add one row and if you want to add the row at last so you can write this code after your code like this,

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lstABC = new ABCRepository().FetchActiveABC();
            DataGridView.DataSource = lstABC;

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
        }
```

Comment: Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.